# How to do an autocomplete in asp.net with a ListView?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, listview, autocomplete

I am trying to implement an autocomplete on a asp:TextBox which is located in an asp:ListView. I wrote a WebService.asmx that does retrieve the values properly outside the ListView.

I tried the WebService.asmx which does the autocomplete properly when outside of the ListView. 
I attempted to reproduce the same thing, but this time in an asp:ListView, ItemTemplate. I do not get any error, but I don't get any autocomplete options either.
I tried many ways to retreive the TextBox.ClientID, but nothing works..

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
OUTSIDE LISTVIEW (It works)

```
<script>
      var txtSearch = $('#<%= txtUser.ClientID %>');
      txtSearch.autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                  var param = { searchTerm: txtSearch.val() };
                  $.ajax({
                        url: "WebServices.asmx/GetLogInUsers",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                              response(data.d)
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                              alert(result);
                        }
                  });
            },
            minLength: 3
      });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
FOR LISTVIEW

```
<script>
a) var txtSearch = $("*[id$=lvMyGestionnaires] input[id$=txtLvADID]");
b) var txtSearch = $("*[id=lvMyGestionnaires] input[id*=txtLvADID]");
c) var txtSearch = $("*[id=lvMyGestionnaires] input[id=txtLvADID]");
d) var txtSearch = $("*[id*=lvMyGestionnaires] input[id*=txtLvADID]");
e) var txtSearch = $('#<%=lvMyGestionnaires.ClientID %> .txtLvADID');
f) var txtSearch = $('#<%=lvMyGestionnaires.ClientID %> input.txtLvADID');
g) var txtSearch = $('*[id$="lvMyGestionnaires"] input.txtLvADID');
      txtSearch.autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                  var param = { searchTerm: txtSearch.val() };
                  $.ajax ({
                        url: "WebServices.asmx/GetLogInUsers",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                              response(data.d)
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                              alert(result);
                        }
                  });
            },
            minLength: 3
      });

</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsers" runat="server" CssClass="txtLvADID"></asp:TextBox>
```

On the first half, the result displays an autocomplete where once you type at least 3 letters, it triggers the autocomplete and display a list of users.

The second half, I tried many ways of retrieving data from the textbox from A to G, inspired from what I have searched online.

Comment: Is your Ajax code outside Listview? Also, add a css class on textbox and then try using that css class selector

Comment: The ajax is outside the ListView, and the cssClass for that textbox is "txtLvADID"

Comment: Try with simple css class selector e.g. `$('.txtLvADID').autocomplete({..})`

Comment: It still doesn't make any difference. Is there a way to test/debug Javascript/ajax?

Comment: You can write `debugger;` statement in your javascript code and then refresh the browser, launch developer tools by pressing F12 and then perform the action which will cause pause the code execution at debugger statement and from there onwards you can debug line by line.

Comment: This time, I was able to "fix" it. I merged together the Javascript from the first and second block. This time, the result is a bit weird.
In the ListView, lets say I have the txtA, txtB, txtC; if I type in txtB, it will only show that I wrote in txtA. I think the clientID has something to do with this situation. Any Idea?

Comment: Share your latest code with Listview as well as autocomplete code snippet